# Speed up uglify in grunt

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, uglifyjs

In my angular application I am using grunt for various utilities. One of them is uglify. I am using it to create two minified files, one for my own code another for third party code. My code contains 21 files and third party contains around 23 files. So because of this huge number it takes almost 4 mins to minify all script. I was wondering if there is any way out to decrease this time because even for a small change I have to wait 4 mins to see. I was thinking if I can parallelise those two minification then i could reduce the minification time. So my question is, is this achievable in any way?

Comment: Do you use the most recent version of uglify? and are you using grunt-ng-min of grunt-ng-annotateng? grunt-ng-annotate is much faster.

Comment: Also consider checking your changing with grunt serve and mocking the responses with ng mock. This saves a lot of build time, since you only need to reload the page to see your changes.

Comment: We have 574 own JavaScript files and 1405 more in dependencies. The "uglification" takes only a few seconds. Your problem might be elsewhere.

Comment: I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Few months back I used uglify to minify and it took only few seconds. Now it takes almost 4 mins to uglify.
@AndrePaap: I am only using uglify's latest version.

Comment: I observed that minifying of already minified files took considerable longer, but not this much longer. Sorry I don't have any more siggestions. Like @Oleg it takes only seconds for my projects.

Comment: same problem here...

Comment: @archiehicox what I have done is that I have divided files in two parts and using grunt concurrent I am parallelly minifying files which saves me small amount of time.

Comment: @ShubhamParamhans My bottleneck are uglifying the many bower libraries. Is there way to split the uglify task in the concurrent one?

Comment: @archiehicox, in uglify divide your minification files in diff files and in concurrent run those uglify. If you want exact code, I can mail you.